# 1 Primary Key pointing to multiple colums

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, visual-paradigm

My intention here is to have COLUMNS`("assignedTo" , "loggedBy" , "completedBy" )` to have a reference to multiple records of `"Employee"` , `"ID"` I would have to assume it would be a many to many relationship however I'm oblivious to how it should be implemented.

Here's an a screenshot of my ERD demonstrating what my database currently looks like:

[image: Screenshot of ERD]

Comment: Sounds like you're saying a Task can be loggedBy, assignedTo, or completedBy multiple Employees, and similarly an Employee can have multiple things that they logged, are assigned to or that they completed? Is this a correct understanding of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you'll need to use join/junction tables as suggested by @Bas.

I believe the actual tables creating the relationship you want will need to look something like this:

[image: An example database structure using junction tables for 3 many to many relationships.]

(My diagram leaves out some of the other tables which I don't think are important to illustrate the concept of many-to-many relationships that use junction tables.)

You'll note that I've removed the loggedBy, assignedTo and completedBy columns from your Task table. When doing a many to many relationship you don't need them. The info about those connections between tables is stored in the junction tables.

Why do we have to do this?

Let's just use the AssignedTo relationship as an example...

Since we don't know how many Employees might be assigned to a Task we can't make columns for the Employees' ids in the Tasks table. Likewise, since we don't know how many Tasks an Employee might be assigned to we can't make column for the Tasks' ids in the Employees table. If we tried to, we might not have enough columns or we might have too many columns. Neither of these are good problems to have.

Instead, we put a new entry in the related junction table every time we want to make a connection between tables that have many-to-many relationships. We can add as many connections or as few connections as we want without any problems.

Hopefully that makes a bit more sense. Things certainly can look more confusing when you're trying to model many-to-many relationships in a relational database.

Comment: I finally understand how this works xD took some time but worth it. I can't thank you enough for all your help and time.

Comment: Great. Glad to hear this made sense!

Answer (score 1):

If each of `"assignedTo"` , `"loggedBy"` , `"completedBy"` can be exercised by multiple employees (this also implies an employee can have multiple `"assignedTo"`, `"loggedBy"` or `"completedBy"`) it means it is a many-to-many relationship (as you suggested). To accomplish this you make a many-to-many relationship 'joint' table for `"assignedTo"`, `"loggedBy"` and `"completedBy"` each (this will replace your columns by 'joint' tables). You do this in the same way as your `'EmployeeTask'` table. This 'joint' table is also called 'Associative entity'. See Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity

Note: an ERD should not contain 'join' tables. A many-to-many relationship is modeled using two 'crow foots' at both sides. These 'joint' tables will only appear in the 'Physical Data Model' (PDM).

Comment: would this require me to make `"assignedTo" , "loggedBy" and "completedBy"` Primary keys in the table `Task`?

Comment: @T.Pilvelis No, don't do that. Look at foreign keys: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp . Wikipedia has a nice explanation of many-to-may tables here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity

Comment: It actually looks like your ERD has something very similar to a junction/join table already, i.e. the `EmployeeTask` table.

What is the purpose of that table? It seems like it's trying to show that a Tasks can belong to many employees, and an Employee can have many tasks.

To do the 3 many-to-many relationships you describe you'll need 3 junction tables like @Bas is suggesting.

Comment: @Bas @Ectropy I apologise, I'm not quite sure I'm understanding the concept. If I create many to many relationships with `Employee` and `Task` it will take the primary keys from both tables to create the joint table. Surely to make this possible I would have to make `"assignedTo" "loggedBy" and "completedBy"` PK's

Comment: Actually, you can just use the primary key of the task and the primary key of the employee, and put that in a junction table. Those three columns `("assignedTo" "loggedBy" and "completedBy")` won't be needed anymore. See my answer for an idea of why this is.